# Find the product $S1.S2$ in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the figure, $ABCD$ is an isosceles trapezoid ( $BC \parallel AD$),
$M, N, P$ and $Q$ are midpoints and $S_{AMR} = 4 m^2$
Calculate: $S1.S2$ (Answer:$64m^2$)
[image]

I couldn't understand this resolution .. could anyone clarify or present another solution?

$MN = QP = \frac{AC}{2}\\
NP = MQ = \frac{BD}{2} = \frac{AC}{2}\\
BD \cap MN = X\\
\triangle BXM \cong  \triangle AMR \\
XNTJ \sim TQRS \sim MNPQ  \implies \boxed{S_{MXTR}=8 \implies \sqrt{S1.S2}=8}???\\
\therefore S1.S2 = 64$

Now, I was able to understand
$S_{ABT} = 4S_{RMA} = 16\\
S_{BMX} = S_{RMA} = 4 \therefore S_{XMRT} = 8 = S_{TJPS}\\
S1.S2 =8^2 = 64$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_{MXTR} = 2 \cdot S_{\triangle ARM} =8$

Note that $NJTX$ and $RTSQ$ are rhombus and hence $S_{MXTR} = \sqrt{S_1 \cdot S_2}$. Here is another way to look at it -

By midpoint theorem, $MQ \parallel BD$ and $AR = RT$. Similarly, $MN \parallel AC$

Also, can you see $\triangle ARQ \cong \triangle DSQ$ and $\triangle BXN \cong \triangle CJN$?

So, $NJTX$ and $RTSQ$ are rhombus with lengths $RM$ and $AR$ respectively. If $\angle ARM = \theta$,

$S_1 = RM^2 \sin\theta, S_2 = AR^2 \sin\theta$

$S_1 \cdot S_2 = (2 \cdot \frac 1 2 \cdot AR \cdot RM \cdot \sin\theta)^2 = (2 \cdot S_{\triangle ARM})^2 = 64$